How do I simulate a beam/particle bouncing off the inside of an ellipse in Desmos?
I have graphed an ellipse based on two focal points locked to the x-axis. I'm trying to figure out how to make the beam I made inside the ellipse bounce off of the inside surface and change trajectory, which in theory should cause it to hit the other focal point. The Desmos link below has my equations so far, and I need help making the beam bounce. Once I get that, I will create several of them and hopefully be able to show that my ellipse works correctly. Please don't steal it.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bn2dpyuyrf

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is a cool concept! I checked out the Desmos graph, and it's a little hard for me to understand what the different variables mean in context. Could you explain those? I have an idea for a solution, but it might take a while for me to articulate it.

Here's a graph I made a while ago that does simulate reflections of an ellipse that might help: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tvgzexpum7

It is difficult for me to understand what is your exact objective. But if you want to simulate successive "ordinary" reflections, here is a short program written in Matlab which does the job for an ellipse with equation
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \tag{1}$$

with notations
$$\vec{PQ}=d \vec{V}\tag{2}$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are consecutive impact points on the trajectory, $d$ is distance $PQ$ and $\vec{V}$ is a (unit norm) directing vector of line $PQ$.
$N$ is the normal vector in point $Q$
The new vector $V'$ is obtain by reflection of the old vector $V$ with respect to this normal vector, i.e., by the operation called "Householder reflection formula" :
$$V'=V-2(N.V)N \tag{3}$$
(where $N.V$ is the dot product)
It should not be difficult for you to adapt this program to Desmos :
 a=3;b=2;A=a^2;B=b^2;
 f=sqrt(a^2-b^2); % focal distance OF
 plot([-f,f],[0,0],'ok'); % foci
 t=0:0.01:2*pi;plot(a*cos(t),b*sin(t)); % ellipse
 x0=0.05;V=[-1;-0.8],
 y0=b*sqrt(1-(x0/a)^2); % due to equ. (1)
 P=[x0;y0]; % initial point
 V=[-1;-0.8]; % initial shooting direction from P
 nbe=340; % number of impacts
 for p=2:nbe;
    u=V(1);v=V(2);
    k=-2*(B*u*x0+A*v*y0)/(B*u^2+A*v^2);
    Q=P+k*V; % equ. (2)
    plot([P(1),Q(1)],[P(2),Q(2)]);hold on;
    P=Q
    x0=P(1);y0=P(2);
    N=[y0/B;-x0/A];N=N/norm(N);% unit normal vector
    V=V-2*(N'*V)*N; % see equ. (3)
 end;

Remarks :

I can give details about expression $k=...$ (second instruction in the loop).

$V$ has been chosen here in such a way that initial ray $PQ$ doesn't cross the interfocal line $F_1F_2$ ; it is why we have one of the classical configuration where the rays envelope another ellipse  with the same foci.



A very nice set of properties of elliptical billiards can be found in Dan Reznik site here
